# Size of a TextView within a widget

Tags: android, widget, textview

I want to squeeze as much text as possible into one TextView of a widget, so I want to hyphenate the text contents of that particular TextView. The easiest way to retrieve the size of the TextView, I figure out, would be to inflate the whole widget with the size of the display. Then I would increase the text contents of the TextView and watch when the number of lines property changes, so that I know where to put the hyphen ('-').

This off-screen measuring works, but it seems that I'm setting some dimensions wrong, as the off-screen method detects new lines earlier than what is drawn on the actual widget, i.e. the actual widget seems to be wider than what I reproduce off-screen.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to achieve what I want?

Here's some code:

1) The off-screen text measurement

```
String adaptText(String text) {
  Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
    .getDefaultDisplay();

  // I'm aware these methods are deprecated, but the results are identical
  // when I'm using the new method: display.getSize(point)
  int displayWidth = display.getWidth();
  int displayHeight = display.getHeight();

  LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(this);
  LinearLayout sampleLayout = (LinearLayout) LinearLayout.inflate(this,
      R.layout.kal_medium, root);   
  sampleLayout.measure(displayWidth, displayHeight);        
  sampleLayout.layout(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

  TextView saintsView = (TextView) sampleLayout.findViewById(R.id.saints);
  StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder(); // result holder

  int numLines = 1; // there's always one line at least
  int len = text.length();

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    saintsView.setText(textBuilder);
    if (saintsView.getLineCount() > numLines) {      
      System.out.println("=========BROKEN AT:" + textBuilder);

      // here goes the code that inserts the hyphen

      numLines++;
    }
    textBuilder.append(text.charAt(i));
  }
  return textBuilder.toString();
}
```

2) The widget layout file: kal_medium.xml, not in whole.

```
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_bg"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_post"/>

...

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/date"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    ...            

   <TextView android:id="@+id/saints"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had left aside this problem, and when I revisited I found the solution:

my actual idea proposed in the question works, there's just a bug in the algorithm for the insertion of the hyphen. Just make sure you know exactly what your lines would contain once you insert the hyphen.